# D3 Click event is not triggering once we add the Pattern fill to the svg in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, onclicklistener, fill

I am using *D3JS* for plotting the graph that has *rects* and I am using the 
*Patterns* as a fill and  it is like this,

```
var patterns = svg.append('defs');
patterns.append("pattern")
        .attr('id',"fillId")
        .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
        .attr('width', 8)
        .attr('height', 8)
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l4,-4 M0,8 l8,-8 M6,10 l4,-4')
        .attr('stroke', "black")
        .attr('stroke-width', 2);
```

And I am adding a fill to SVG like this

```
svg.append("g")
   .append("circle")
   .attr({cx:"60",cy:"60",r:"50", fill:"url(#fillId)" })
   .on("click",function(d,i){
       //click event is not triggering.
   })
   .on("contextmenu",function(d,i){
     //This works fine.
   });
```

But even though I have added a *d3 click listener* to circle the click event is not triggering since I am using *pattern fill* and *d3 right click* event will work normally.How to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *d3 right click*? If you have another event listener, edit your question to add that information. That being said, the click event **is** working.

Comment: means D3 contextmenu event, it is working fine

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: They are both working: https://jsfiddle.net/qnzswf9u/